# Batik SVG to PDF - PDFTranscoder - missing Labels

Tags: java, pdf, svg, batik

I was converting an SVG File into PDF using Apache Batik but labels are missing in the PDF

The following code is used to generate PDF:

```
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
...

File svgFile = new File("./target/test.svg");
...

PDFTranscoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(svgFile); FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("./target/test-batik.pdf"))) {
    TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(fileInputStream);
    TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(fileOutputStream);
    transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
}
```

### Dependency

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
     <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
     <version>1.10</version>
   </dependency>
```

How can I convert svg to PDF with labels?

Comment: Apache Batik uses system fonts for rendering text in the SVG file. If the fonts used in the SVG file are not available on the system where the conversion is performed, you may encounter font substitution issues.

Comment: Is there any way to set default font if the font is not available in system?

Comment: Yes, I think you can use an UserAgent and set it PDFTranscoder. You can override getFontFamilyResolver() for that UserAgent.